# Htaccess rewrite does not work as expected

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have this problem which is taking a lot of time and I'm stuck:
If you go in this website:

```
http://95.85.28.132/cosafarea.it/viareggio/pub
```

you see the nothing found page,
but if you click on the search it shows you the correct listing.
The strange thing is that the rewrite rule works as expected since as you can see in the first url it correctly fills in the 2 fields, but in some way the outcome is different and I cannot see the items when I launche the rewrited url.
This is the htaccess rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /cosafarea.it/?s=&geo-radius=15&geo-lat=&geo-lng=&categories=$2&locations=$1&dir-search=yes&post_type=ait-dir-item [NC,L]
```

Any clue? Thank you, best.

Comment: Is your rule in the `cosafarea.it` folder?

Comment: @EmanueleStrano: What is location of this .htaccess?

Comment: the htaccess is in /var/www/cosafarea.it
I want to make everything work before moving the dns to the proper address (cosafarea.it).
The rewrite rule has the correct base: RewriteBase /cosafarea.it/

Also, the rewrite is working for other rules, such as: 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /cosafarea.it/?s=&geo-radius=15&geo-lat=&geo-lng=&categories=0&locations=$1&dir-search=yes&post_type=ait-dir-item [NC,L]

which practically lets me write:
    95.85.28.132/cosafarea.it/viareggio/
instead of the long url